# centering a div elemnt with percent width and height with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a calculator interface with HTML and CSS and I want the main div element always remain at the center of the screen  even when I change the size of the screen, I want the element to have `80%` width and `70%` height and with minimum height of `280px` and maximum width of `580px`.

```css
#main{
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:580px;
    min-height:280px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">sth
<div>
```

I have tried many ways but none worked for me, many ways set the element at the center horizontally but not vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `display: flex` at top level element

Hope this helps, cheers!

```css
#main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

#calculator {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width:580px;
    min-height:280px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="calculator">sth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the div element is not centered vertically

Comment: I see. 
I've fixed it, now should be OK to center vertically ;)

Answer (score 1):

Position `#main` div.

```css
#main{
    height: 70%;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 580px;
    min-height: 280px;
    background: bisque;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    My Calculator
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main{

}
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
.justify {
    text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="center">
<div class="justify">
<b>Note: </b>Using margin:auto will not work in IE8, unless a !DOCTYPE is declared. so don't forget that, hope this help you
</div>
</div>

<p class="justify">What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```